# AnalysisException error in hive using lag func

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table which has some fields like name, id,errors, date_timestamp.

Name, id & date_timestamp are STRING, while errors is also STRING

Iam trying to get the previous value of errors field as below,

```
(lag(errors,1) over (partition by name, id order by date_timestamp) - errors) as err_calculate
```

I am getting the below error while executing the above code.

`AnalysisException: Arithmetic operation requires numeric operands`

I tried using `cast()` but no luck. Any help would be useful. Thanks.

Comment: Either `errors` is not `bigint`, or the error comes from another part of your query.

Comment: Errors comes from another part of query.

Answer (score 0):

Try the query below. If you're in the first row of the window, lag returns NULL and hive complains that it cannot do something like NULL - 1.

```
case when lag(errors,1) over (partition by name, id order by date_timestamp) is not null
then (lag(errors,1) over (partition by name, id order by date_timestamp) - errors) 
else null 
end as err_calculate
```

Comment: This makes no sense because  `NULL - errors` result is null. Try `select null - 1` for example.

Comment: @leftjoin I agree this makes no sense, but this nonsensical behaviour seems to be a bug of Hive: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-8664

Comment: I see. It is definitely Impala, because the exception is the same

Comment: Errors field is not BIGINT, but it's STRING. sry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find rows with not bigint values in `errors` you will see what is wrong with them

```
select * from ...
where errors is not null                -- not null
 and cast(errors as bigint) is null     -- and not bigint
```

cast returns null when the value cannot be casted